# Is there a way to generalize the orths inside the argument of Spacy's retokenizer.split?

Tags: python, split, nlp, spacy

I'm tryng to fix wronly merged spanish words from a text file and I'm using Spacy's retokenizer.split, however, I would like to generalize the orth's arguments inside retokenizer.split. I have the next code

```
doc= nlp("the wordsare wronly merged and weneed split them") #example
words = ["wordsare"] # Example: words to be split
matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)
patterns = [nlp.make_doc(text) for text in words]
matcher.add("Terminology", None, *patterns)
matches = matcher(doc)
with doc.retokenize() as retokenizer:
    for match_id, start, end in matches:
        heads = [(doc[start],1), doc[start]]
        attrs = {"POS": ["PROPN", "PROPN"], "DEP": ["pobj", "compound"]}
        orths= [str(doc[start]),str(doc[end])]
    retokenizer.split(doc[start], orths=orths, heads=heads, attrs=attrs)
token_split=[token.text for token in doc]
print(token_split)
```

But when I put the orths this way `orths= [str(doc[start]),str(doc[end])]` and not `["words","are"]` I get this error:

> **ValueError: [E117] The newly split tokens must match the text of the original token. New orths: wordsarewronly. Old text: wordsare.**

I would like some help with the generalization of that, because i want the code no just fix the word **wordsare** but also with the word **weneed** and others that the file could have.

Answer (score 1):

What I would change in your example is:

1. `words = ["wordsare"]` to `words = ["wordsare","weneed"]`
   That is the list of wrongly spelled words.
2. Add rules for splitting that map to the first list: `splits = {"wordsare":["words","are"], "weneed":["we","need"]}`
3. `orths= [str(doc[start]),str(doc[end])]` to `orths= splits[doc[start:end].text]`
   this is a list of splits to substitute the match found.  Your original `[str(doc[start]),str(doc[end])]` does not make too much sense.
4. Move `retokenizer.split` into the loop.
5. Think about adding another dictionary for `attrs`

As soon you have it place, you have a working and generalizing example:

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

doc= nlp("the wordsare wronly merged and weneed split them") #example
words = ["wordsare","weneed"] # Example: words to be split
splits = {"wordsare":["words","are"], "weneed":["we","need"]}
matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)
patterns = [nlp.make_doc(text) for text in words]
matcher.add("Terminology", None, *patterns)
matches = matcher(doc)

with doc.retokenize() as retokenizer:
    for match_id, start, end in matches:
        heads = [(doc[start],1), doc[start]]
        attrs = {"POS": ["PROPN", "PROPN"], "DEP": ["pobj", "compound"]}
        orths= splits[doc[start:end].text]           
        retokenizer.split(doc[start], orths=orths, heads=heads, attrs=attrs)
token_split=[token.text for token in doc]
print(token_split) 
['the', 'words' ,'are', 'wronly', 'merged', 'and', 'we', 'need', 'split', 'them']
```

Note, if you're only concerned with tokenization, there is much easier, and perhaps faster way to do the same:

```
[splits[tok.text] if tok.text in words else tok.text for tok in doc]
['the', 'words', 'are', 'wronly', 'merged', 'and', 'we', 'need', 'split', 'them']
```

Also note, in the first example `attrs` are fixed and wrongly assigned for some cases. You may take care of that by making another dictionary, but more straitforward and clean way to have a fully functional pipeline, is to redefine tokenizer and let `spacy` do the rest for you:

```
from spacy.tokens import Doc
nlp.make_doc = lambda txt: Doc(nlp.vocab, [i for l in [splits[tok.text] if tok.text in words else [tok.text] for tok in nlp.tokenizer(txt)] for i in l])
doc2 = nlp("the wordsare wronly merged and weneed split them")
for tok in doc2:
    print(f"{tok.text:<10}", f"{tok.pos_:<10}", f"{tok.dep_:<10}")
the        DET        det       
words      NOUN       nsubjpass 
are        AUX        auxpass   
wronly     ADV        advmod    
merged     VERB       ROOT      
and        CCONJ      cc        
we         PRON       nsubj     
need       VERB       aux       
split      VERB       conj      
them       PRON       dobj
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sergey, I will check it, but I still have the doubt about generalize **splits = {"wordsare":["words","are"], "weneed":["we","need"]}**, because it is being given manually

Comment: You need to provide split rules, there is no way around it.

Comment: @IlianaVargas Does it answer your question? Was it helpful? Please consider https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers